# how to limit the drawing zone with core Graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics

I am making a drawing app, I have problems with Core Graphics, I am drawing black circles , using an array of cgpoints to reference the center of that circle, the problem is if the cgpoint is near or in the limit on the right side of the iphone screen width, the app draws the rest of the black circle in the left side

```
           for (int ii = 0; ii<[groupOfMissingPixelsArray count]; ii++) {
                @autoreleasepool{
                NSValue *vlalue = [groupOfMissingPixelsArray objectAtIndex:ii];
                CGPoint currentPoint = [vlalue CGPointValue];
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
                CGRect circlePoint = CGRectMake(currentPoint.x-15,currentPoint.y-15, 30, 30);
                CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circlePoint);
                CGRect lastCircle = CGRectMake([[groupOfMissingPixelsArray lastObject] CGPointValue].x-5, [[groupOfMissingPixelsArray lastObject] CGPointValue].y-5, 10, 10);
                CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, lastCircle);
                CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
                CGContextClipToRect(ctx,backGroundRect);
                CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
                background.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                }
            }
        }
```

you can see below more precisely the problem that I have 
[image: afert drawing the black circles around the yellow ones, which represents the array of cgpoints]

Please tell what I am doing wrong,, thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks anyway, I just solved!!!!

Comment: You should really consider writing up the solution you found, in case someone else runs into the same issue later.